# How to run a Progress program from .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, openedge, progress-4gl

I instantiate a .NET/C# class from a Progress session like this

```
DEFINE VARIABLE myObj as CLASS MyClass.
myObj = NEW MyClass("param").
/* do something with myObj ... */
```

As I understand, the `myObj` instance runs "in the Progress session". So it should be possible to call another Progress program from `myObj` (which is .NET code), i.e. I need a statement in C# that can run a Progress program (like `RUN program.p.` in Progress, but in C#).

Is it possible to do so? Are there other possibilities to run a Progress program from a .NET object, which is running in a Progress session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the .NET object is executed within the Progress runtime, you can subscribe to .NET events (as long as they are implementing a System.EventHandler derived signature).

myObj:MyEvent:Subscribe ("EventHandlerProcedure") .

```
PROCEDURE EventHandlerProcedure:
    DEFINE INPUT PARAMETER sender AS System.Object    NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE INPUT PARAMETER e      AS System.EventArgs NO-UNDO .

END PROCEDURE.
```

The other possible call-back mechanism requires OO-ABL. An OO-ABL class can implement an .NET interface and then can be called from .NET objects.